# How to capture connection information in Binary Log file in MySQl 5.1.51

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL server 5.1.51 and want to enable Binary Logging. But except the information like Server ID,time of execution,sql statement that fired etc. is it possible to log the connection details including place and/or IP, from which the query was fired on the server. So that it can be identified who and from where modified the data either by connecting with application, direct access to the server or by remote access to the server.

Comment: You want the [General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html).

Comment: I enabled both General Query Log and Binary Log, but none of them provide me the IP/Place related information. Thanks @Kmeixner

Comment: General Log gives me only user@hostname. But a number of user access the application. Web.config has same credentials to connect to server database. Therefore all user will be logged in GeneralLogs with same user@hostname. So if two users accessing the application from two different location  entries in GeneralLog will be same, because for making the connection to MySQL server same web.config is used. Therefor I need location/IP. If some other solution is possible please share.Some alternate way will also be appreciable. Thanks @Eggyal

Comment: So far as MySQL is concerned, all operations are performed by the webserver.  It has no visibility over why the web server has issued its commands, nor for whom.  The logging that you desire should occur within the web application, on the webserver, where such information is visible and known—not within MySQL.

Comment: Thanks @Eggyal. I got your point. The real situation is like this-
Somebody opened the server either by direct access or by taking it on remote,then person logged in to MySQL server,modified the data in some database tables.Person did not modified the data using application deployed on the server. We want to know from which location or IP connection was established and what queries were fired. Please share your thoughts on this. If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, the person has obtained shell access, from which they have logged into MySQL using the webserver/application's credentials?  And you want to identify who they were/from where they were connecting?  That is then a task for the operating system, which controls access to the shell that they used.

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Also on the server MySQL Query Browser is installed. After making connection to the server person may have logged in using MySQL Query Browser and fired the queries. Could you share any link, if you have, related to the topic.

Comment: Anybody please share some link or solution related to the topic.